# Python-Beautiful Soup "find_all" only return one result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a file like this

```
<a>
    <b>1</b>
</a>
<a>
    <b>2</b>
</a>
<a>
    <b>3</b>
</a>
```

and i want all the information inside  so i wrote this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
infile = open("testA.xml",'r')
contents = infile.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
result = soup.find_all('a')
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[<a>
<b>1</b>
</a>]
```

I don't understand why i can retrieve all the info from the file. I want something like this:

```
[<a>
<b>1</b>
</a>, 
<a>
<b>2</b>
</a>, 
<a>
<b>3</b>
</a>]
```

Thank you all

Comment: Shouldn't your file contain an XML-header?

Comment: ya that's it, i had a function to write the file and i forgot to write de xml-header thank you @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @1pati2: you can also use `lxml` in which case the header is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your file is truly an XML file, it should contain an XML header.

If it is not, you can use **`lxml`** as parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
infile = open("testA.xml",'r')
contents = infile.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(contents,'lxml')
result = soup.find_all('a')
print(result)
```

Mind that you better use a context (`with`) when you read from files, so you can make it more elegant with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("testA.xml",'r') as infile:
    contents = infile.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(contents,'lxml')
    result = soup.find_all('a')
    print(result)
```

This will enforce Python to close the file once jumping out of the `with` scope.

Running this in Python3 gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> infile = open("testA.xml",'r')
>>> contents = infile.read()
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(contents,'lxml')
>>> result = soup.find_all('a')
>>> result
[<a>
<b>1</b>
</a>, <a>
<b>2</b>
</a>, <a>
<b>3</b>
</a>]
```

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is that you don't have a root tag. change your xml file to

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>2</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>3</b>
    </a>
</content>`
```

you can change content accordingly.